# How do I determine my total app users from a specific country?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to find out how many app users I have from a specific country. I know insights will show me how many users I have in each of my top twenty countries, but does anyone know how to find out your total number of app users from a country that is not in your application's top twenty?

Answer (score 0):

Your options are basically:

1. Check the user's current IP with something like [GeoIP](http://www.maxmind.com/app/php)
   *... I did some testing with GeoIP in the past, but the results didn't really convince me*
2. Implement analytics code (I'm currently using Google Analytics)
3. If, and only IF this information is absolutely critical then you should look into the "user_location" and "user_hometown" [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

PS: Remember to update your Privacy Policy if you are going to do anything with the user's IP